# Why does this .each() iteration only work on the last element?

Tags: jquery

Here's my code.

```
$(function(){
$(".stars").each(function(){starMap($(this))});
});
function starMap(elem)
{
 var p=elem.attr("rel");
 var t=-(5-p)*30;
 elem.css("background-position","0 "+t);
}
```

See JSfiddle here at [http://jsfiddle.net/bEVn9/3](http://jsfiddle.net/bEVn9/)

Comment: Your problem description is flawed because you have jumped to a conclusion without proving it, or analysing it thoroughly enough. In fact, the iteration must work just fine, so something else (not what you assumed) is causing whatever symptoms you see (that you haven't described). Describe _symptoms_ (vs characteristic expected behaviour), not _predictions_ (unless you have proved them already).

Comment: Looking at your jsFiddle post, I have no idea what it's doing or what you want it to do. You also didn't even set jQuery in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually runs thru all elements. Make it Pixel values in your css:

```
elem.css("background-position","0px "+t+"px");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bEVn9/2/

Comment: Thank you, can't believe that's the reason. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is looping through each element correctly, however your `.css()` call is setting the background position incorrectly.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/bEVn9/5/) amended fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
elem.css("background-position","0 "+ t + "px");
```

Note the added *px*.